# are strtol, strtoll, strtod safe for any chars, even not null terminated?

Tags: c, linux, string

I am trying to convert some chars into numeric type, but some of them may not be null-terminated strings. So are strtol, strtoll, strtod safe for those strings that aren't null-terminated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

If a character array is not terminated by a null character, then *it's not a string*.  If any of the `strto*()` functions are passed an argument that doesn't point to a string, the behavior is undefined.

Referring to the [latest draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) of the 2011 ISO C standard:

> **7.1.1 Definition of terms:**
>
> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and
>   including the first null character.
>
> **7.1.4 Use of library functions:**
>
> If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as a value
>   outside the domain of the function, or a pointer outside the address
>   space of the program, or a null pointer, or a pointer to
>   non-modifiable storage when the corresponding parameter is not
>   const-qualified) or a type (after promotion) not expected by a
>   function with variable number of arguments, the behavior is undefined.
>
> **7.22.1.3 The `strtod`, `strtof`, and `strtold` functions:**
>
> The `strtod`, `strtof`, and `strtold` functions convert the **initial portion of the *string* pointed to by *nptr* to `double`, `float`, and `long double` representation, respectively.**

(emphasis added)

So an argument that doesn't point to a string is outside the domain of the function.

You're likely to get away with it if the array contains something like `{ '1', '2', '3', 'x', 'y', 'z' }`, since it doesn't need to scan past the `x` that terminates the desired value, but the behavior is explicitly undefined.

If you want to use these functions, you should, if necessary, copy your array into another buffer and explicitly null-terminate it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your input is terminated somehow which is definitely not a valid digit character, processing will stop and shouldn't go happily reading memory until it finds the first NUL.

So I think you're ok.

Comment: So, for example, a blank or punctuation character (or letter when the base does not include that letter) after the converted number will stop the scan.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Except leading spaces, decimal points, anything else that could be valid input, yes.

Comment: @Ben - I was in time to fix my comment with the 'after the converted number' part which was definitely missing in the first revision and was definitely needed.

Comment: @BenVoigt: It *shouldn't*, but I see no guarantee in the standard that it *won't*.